# Convert datetime to varchar from MSSQL to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, type-conversion

how to convert this line of MSSQL to MYSQL

```
SELECT convert(VARCHAR(10), getdate(),106) -- dd mm yyyy
```

I have no idea how to do it in mysql please help..

Comment: You want to get date it dd mm yyyy format in mysql.?

Comment: ya.. getdate() in mssql.. now() in mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DATE_FORMAT function of MYSQL

See
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%W %M %Y');
    -> 'Sunday October 2009'
```

or in your case

```
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%d-%m-%Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)** for the formatting of  date in mysql

```
select DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%d-%m-%Y') as curr_date
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't be sure if this is what you wanted from the question, but you may be able to use this as a possible guideline.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d %m %Y') AS date_variable_name;
```